# Qt resize widget inside another widget

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-designer

I have the following layout:
[image]

The black rectangles are QVBoxLayouts, the red one is a generic widget container and the blue little rectangle is my custom openGL widget.

I already set the resize policies for all layouts and widgets, but I can't get the openGL little widget to resize to the extent of his parent's area (the red rectangle in the image).

I'm a Qt beginner, perhaps I need to use signals and slots to resize the little blue openGL widget to the red one? But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QGLWidget should also be in a layout (of any layout type) to resize itself automatically when its parent is resized.

So, for instance, in the designer, left-click on the red "generic widget container", and choose a vertical layout.

Comment: I'm sorry but the "lay out" menu has every option grayed out. This is weird but I tried it in the first place.. I don't know why but everything's grayed out there

Comment: I ended up adding the openGL widget dinamically by code with this->ui->graphLayout->addWidget(myOpenGLWidget); and now it works, thank you

Comment: @JohnnyPauling If it was grayed out, maybe the GL widget was not a child of the other widget. You could check if it is in the hierarchical tree panel (you can also change the layout from the tree).

Answer (score 1):

In Qt5.4 (i didn't test others) new QOpenGLWidget (inside layout) do not resized automatically in my case. 
I call

```
LayoutWidget->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, event->size().width(), event->size().height()));
```

in resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) of parent widget.